how to solve the unsported_grant_type error when dealing with API integration
I am having this error message:

error ' general exception: Authentication request exception: HTTP request returned status code 400:\n{"error_description":"Invalid grant_type","error":"unsupported_grant_type"}\n'

when using my API methods, despite the token access being granted with the same clientID and secret.
I have tried verifying the .env file to check the client secrets and Id. and i was expecting to be able to work after that.

Can't tell you any more right now, than the error message already did - apparently, you are asking for an invalid grant type. But we don't know what request you are making there. So please go read [ask] and [mre], and then add relevant details to the question.

Make sure the body of your request contains a grant_type or the correct one. I believe your case is client_credentials.
Here is a json:
{
  "grant_type": "client_credentials",
  "client_id": "your_client_id",
  "client_secret": "your_client_secret"
}

Here's a list of all grant_types:
authorization_code
implicit
password
client_credentials
refresh_token
device_code
urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer

You can read more about grant_types here: https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/applications/application-grant-types
